# Установка Puppy linux с винчестера

Tags: установка, linux

Есть работающая Windows XP с интернетом. Диск C:\ имеет файловую систему NTFS. Диск D чистый и сейчас отформатирован в FAT32. Есть CD привод и возможность грузиться с флешки, но нет флешки под рукой, нет загрузочных дисков и привод писать их не умеет. Хочу поставить на диск D Puppy Linux в дуал-бут ( комп слабенький ). Инструкций куча, но старые очень, grubfordos с тех ссылок и не скачать, тем более, что инструкции для "классических" дистрибутивов, а в паппике все иначе. Буду благодарен за любую помощь, намеки и указания правильного направления также принимаются.

Answer (score 1):

Первое, что приходит в голову - записать образ CD на другом компьютере.

Comment: Увы ( ... Но для Puppy Linux есть так называемая frugal установка, в которой достаточно скопировать файлы на диск и прописать путь в меню лист граба. Но какие файлы для нужной версии и как правильно прописывать и как устанавливать граб под виндовсом, имея нтлоадер под нтфс ... Интернеты большие и русскоязычный форум большой у паппика, но только сейчас сформирован алгоритм ... если получится - отпишусь с рецептом.

Comment: Я, честно говоря, сперва  тоже о frugal подумал. Но как увидел там на сайте кучу красных варнингов для виндоюзеров, так и советовать не стал! А похоже, всё-таки, в вашем случае - это единственный способ.

Comment: Но если очень хочется, то вот: http://www.puppylinux.com/hard-puppy.htm Вот там всё и описано! Правда, по-аглицки.